# Why is Android Studio logcat is not showing the current status despite adding the code in main.java and adding the filter?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I am learning to use Android Studio in OSX Catalina 10.15.3 and as per a tutorial to identify which state my app is running currently I wrote the following in MainActivity.java
'

```
package com.example.learn;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG="My Message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i(TAG,"onStart");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG,"onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(TAG,"onPause");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.i(TAG,"onRestart");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i(TAG,"onStop");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG,"onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.i(TAG,"onSaveInstanceState");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG,"onRestoreInstanceState");
    }

}
```

Then I added a logcat filter and this is the screenshot of my filter.
[MY FILTER'S SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Px83.png)

But I am not getting any output in my logcat after applying the filter, I have checked the emulator on which I am running my app and it is same as in the logcat. My app is running successfully and logcat is also showing a lot of things before applying the filter, but after applying the filter it is blank.

Answer (score 0):

try to uncheck "Log Message" & "Package Name" regex.

Comment: try to set "Log Level" to "Info"